# Elasticsearch Java Jest client query builder range with bool query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, range, query-builder, elasticsearch-jest

I need to make an Elasticsearch query using Jest client, to match some terms and a date with a range query. So I need to perform a bool query with a range query using Jest `QueryBuilder` to have a request like this:

```
{
"query": {
    "range": {
        "gte": "begindate",
        "lte": "enddate"
    },
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "field1": [
                        55,
                        99
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "field2": [
                        450
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "field3": [
                        11
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

To do this, I used `queryBuilder` like this :

```
Builder search = null;
Search buildedSearch = null;
SearchResult result = null;

SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

if (field1 != null) {
    qb.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field1", field1));
}

if (field2 != null) {
    qb.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field2", field2));
}

if (field3 != null) {
    qb.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field3", field3));
}

String query = searchSourceBuilder.query(qb).toString();

if (field != null) {
    search = new Search.Builder(query).addIndex(index).addType(type);
    if (beginIndex != -1) {
        search.setParameter(Parameters.FROM, beginIndex);
    }

    if (endIndex != -1) {
        search.setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, endIndex);
    }

    buildedSearch = search.build();
}

try {
    result = client.execute(buildedSearch);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.info("Can't found result");
}
```

How can I add a range query on the search builder, because my object `qb` has already a boolquery, and I can't add a range query to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
QueryBuilder rangeQuery = QueryBuilders
.rangeQuery("field")
.from("2016-01-01||/D")
.to("2017-01-01||/D")
.includeLower(true)
.includeUpper(false);


QueryBuilder termsQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field1","12"))
.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("field2", "abc"))
.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("field3", "def"));


QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
.boolQuery()
.should(rangeQuery)
.should(termsQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a range query like below:

```
QueryBuilder rangeQ = QueryBuilders
                    .rangeQuery("begindate")
                    .from(5)
                    .to(10);
```

then combine the two queries with a should:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .should(rangeQ)
                    .should(boolQ);
```

Take a look at this post: [How to construct a boolquery dynamically in java api?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-construct-a-boolquery-dynamically-in-java-api/11396/2) for more information.