# How to use elasticsearch rangequery to find values that are less than or equal to a number value in Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hello I'm new to Elastic Search and I'm trying to build an elastic search query using Java API. I have the following.

```
int count = 7
QueryBuilder findRangeNumber = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("numberField").lte(count);
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(findRangeNumber);
```

This return numberField that are equal to 12,6,4, and, 5. I want it to return values where numberField is less than or equal to count (so the number 6,5, and 4 in the example).

If I change number count to 12 it only return numberField that are equal to 12. I'm confuse to how this works and if it possible to it return any value of numberField that is less than or equal to count.

I also have tried the following with no luck

```
int count = 7
QueryBuilder findRangeNumber = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("numberField").lte(count).gte(0);
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(findRangeNumber);
```

This is what the query look like when I print out boolQueryBuilder

```
"must" : [
            {
              "range" : {
                "numberField" : {
                  "from" : null,
                  "to" : 7,
                  "include_lower" : true,
                  "include_upper" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
```

This is what the full code part look like, of what I'm trying to do.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
int count = 7
    if (foo != null) {
        boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("something", matchSomething));
        boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("foobar status")));
    }

    if (foobar != null) {

        BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("someDateField").from(dateField));
        queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("numberField").lte(count));
        boolQuery.must(queryBuilder);

     }

    searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [RangeQueryBuilder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.12.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/RangeQueryBuilder.html) to find values that are less than or equal to a given number

Try out this below code

```
int count=7;
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
RangeQueryBuilder rangeQueryBuilder = new RangeQueryBuilder("numberField").lte(count);
searchSourceBuilder.query(rangeQueryBuilder);
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my-index");
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

---

**Update 1:**

*When you are searching for documents having `numberField` less than equal to 7, you are getting documents having `numberField` value `12,6,4,5`.*

**The search result coming is correct. This is possible only if you have not defined an explicit index mapping, due to which when you have indexed the documents having `numberField`, then it would have been indexed as of `text` type (by default) instead of `numeric` field type.**

Now, lexically `"12","6","4","5"` all are smaller than "7", therefore you are getting all the documents in your search result. And when querying for `"lte":12`, you only get a document having `numberField` equal to 12. This is because there is no document (among these 4) that is lexically smaller than 12.

You can get the index mapping of your index by using [Get Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html).

For the range query to work correctly you need to explicitly define the index mapping for your index, where `numberField` should be mapped to a `numeric` field datatype. You need to delete your index and create a new index with a new index mapping.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "numberField": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Toast please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I tried adding the RangeQueryBuilder to the sourcebuilder but I'm already adding a boolean query to it. Is there a way I keep RangeQuery as a boolean Query?

Comment: @Toast why do you want to add a `BoolQueryBuilder` ? Do you want the range query to be executed inside a `must` clause ?

Comment: looking through a few comments stacking the range query builder on as .should look like in this post here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673744/elasticsearch-java-jest-client-query-builder-range-with-bool-query), but this just made it seem like it wasn't reading any of queries.

Comment: @Toast which version of Elasticsearch are you using ? Are you using JEST client ?

Comment: @Toast can you please share the query, which you want to convert in Java Code ?

Comment: It doesn't have to act like a must clause but I'm already adding a boolean query to check other fields and I don't think I can add two query to the sourcebuilder

Comment: I'm using elasticSearch version 6.4.3. I am not using a Jest Client and I don't have the direct query I want, I'm trying to do this directly through the Java code

Comment: I updated the Question to have more of the original code of what I'm trying to do. Let me know if that helps

Comment: @Toast please go through the updated part of my answer

Comment: your update make sense. I'm having trouble figuring out how that would look with the Java API

Comment: @Toast have you defined any index mapping (explicitly) of your index?

Comment: I don't think I do

Comment: @Toast then you need to define explicit mapping (as shown in the answer above), then your range query will work

Comment: how do I do the above with the Java API?

Comment: @Toast This would be a completely different answer, it would be better if you ask a separate question related to creating index mapping using Java code. You can refer  to this documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-create-index.html

Comment: of course! Thank you so much for your help!